# Drupal: Can't print inside hook_node_insert

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, var-dump

On my Drupal 7 Site I am trying to create my very first own module. I've got a custom node_insert hook like the one below:

```
function sample_node_insert($node){
  dpm($node);
  var_dump($node);
}
```

I just want to see what is inside of $node, but I just can't get it! I tried creating a new node and watching out for some output, but I couldn't manage to find any. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do `exit();` after printing, to make sure no other implementation of this hook get ran.

Comment: thx! the `exit();` did just what I needed. We can close this :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be actually working, you do not even need `var_dump()`. Make sure your theme is displaying messages on the page as `dpm()` puts krumo dump into messages. You can do so by searching for `<?php print $messages; ?>` in the page.tpl.php file of the theme you're using.

Or, if you are testing your code in a page callback function, and you are receiving blank screen, make sure the function returns any string, simple `return "Hello world";` should be enough.

Or, as previously suggested, you can do

```
var_dump($node);
die();
```

but that produces pretty ugly result.